# Problem with initial_layout on Qiskit/IBMQ: 'Not enough qubits in CouplingGraph'

Tags: qiskit, ibm-q-experience, ibm-quantum-devices

I am trying to run an execution on IBMQx2 where I can specify the physical qubits to which I apply gates. The execution without the `initial_layout` runs fine, but the one with it keeps giving me either `"statusCode":400,"name":"Q_OBJECT_NOT_VALID"` or `'Not enough qubits in CouplingGraph'`. Here's the circuit that I use:

```
qr = QuantumRegister(5, 'q')
cr = ClassicalRegister(5)
qc = QuantumCircuit(qr, cr)
qc.h(qr[0])
qc.h(qr[1])
qc.h(qr[2])
qc.h(qr[3])
qc.h(qr[4])
qc.measure(qr, cr)

coupling_map = [[0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 2], [3, 2], [3, 4], [4, 2]]
layout = {0: qr[0], 1: qr[1], 2: qr[2], 3: qr[3], 4: qr[4]}
#layout = {('qr', 0): ('q', 0), ('qr', 1): ('q', 1), ('qr', 2): ('q', 2), ('qr', 3): ('q', 3), ('qr', 4): ('q', 4)}

job_exp = execute(qc, backend=backend, coupling_map=coupling_map, initial_layout=layout, shots=16384)
```

If I use the first layout, it gives me,

> JobError: "{'statusCode': 400, 'name': 'Q_OBJECT_NOT_VALID', 'message': 'Q-Object not valid.', 'code': 'Q_OBJECT_NOT_VALID'}"

which I think may be caused by deprecated syntax or something, so I went on [here](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-tutorials/blob/master/qiskit/terra/using_the_transpiler.ipynb) to find what I hope is a more updated version of `initial_layout`. It got worse: this seems to be even older, and with it another error,

> TranspilerError: 'Not enough qubits in CouplingGraph'`

The problem persists whether I add `coupling_map` in or not. Can anyone tell me how to fix this? Thank you!

Comment: This is not really an answer, but here's something I wrote that works
https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-tutorials/blob/master/community/ignis/repetition_code.ipynb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Q-Object not valid` error you received is caused by the amount of `shots` you set. The max `shots` allowed is 8192. Since the amount of `shots` you set (16384) is greater than the max amount of `shots` allowed, you get that error.

The `TranspilerError` is caused by the second format for `layout`. When I tested your code with the second `layout`, I received this error and a warning stating that the format being used for `initial_layout` was being deprecated. So I would stick to the first format for `layout`.

If you change the amount of `shots` to be <=8192 and use the first format for `layout`, then I believe the code should run.